# Rails 3 - Eager loading on a legacy database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have inherited a web app with the following tables: Categories, SubCategories and Pages. Pages has category_id and sub_category_id columns.

I need to write an efficient query to eager load pages by category and sub_category for iterate in my view (crude example follows):

```
- Category One (categories.each do |category|...)
-- Page One    (category.pages.each do |page|...)
-- SubCategory One (category.sub_categories.each do |sub_category|...
---- Page Two (sub_category.pages.each do |page|...)
```

Category.rb:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :pages
  has_many :sub_categories
end
```

SubCategory.rb:

```
class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :pages
end
```

Page.rb:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :sub_category

  scope :active_pages, :conditions => {:is_active => true}
end
```

I've experimented with queries like the following with little success where the sub_categories are concerned:

```
Category.includes(:sub_categories, :pages).where('pages.is_active = 1')
```

Categories works great, but I'm not sure how to eager load the sub_categories. Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [this article](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2089) which I was just looking at something like this might do what you want:

```
Category.find( :all, :include => [ :pages, { :sub_categories => :pages } ] )
```

Comment: Thanks, Noel. This worked like a charm (I rewrote the syntax for Activerecord 3) and rendering went from 1200ms to 200ms. Thanks again.